# XAML binding UI update

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

If I have XAML element that is binded to a data source property and the data source changes faster then the human eye can see I am assuming that the UI also gets re drawn faster then the human eye can see and wasting resources. Would it be a good idea for the property change to raise a flag instead of triggering re-draw of UI and then a timer to trigger the UI redraw if the property was changed? or am I missing how the UI gets re-drawn?

Comment: Is it just a grid? Or the entire UI?.

Comment: If the data source is firing INotifyPropertyChanged events, then the grid will be responding to them. Could you implement a timer to fire PropertyChanged less often? eg. After 500ms, if the property has changed and the event has not fired, then fire the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *Could* use a delyed invocation of raising the property changed event, maybe like this...

```
public static class DispatcherExtensions
{
    private static Dictionary<string, DispatcherTimer> timers =
        new Dictionary<string, DispatcherTimer>();
    private static readonly object syncRoot = new object();

    public static void DelayInvoke(this Dispatcher dispatcher, string namedInvocation,
        Action action, TimeSpan delay,
        DispatcherPriority priority = DispatcherPriority.Normal)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            RemoveTimer(namedInvocation);
            var timer = new DispatcherTimer(delay, priority, (s, e) => action(), dispatcher);
            timer.Start();
            timers.Add(namedInvocation, timer);
        }
    }


    public static void CancelNamedInvocation(this Dispatcher dispatcher, string namedInvocation)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            RemoveTimer(namedInvocation);
        }
    }

    private static void RemoveTimer(string namedInvocation)
    {
        if (!timers.ContainsKey(namedInvocation)) return;
        timers[namedInvocation].Stop();
        timers.Remove(namedInvocation);
    } 


}
```

Then

```
private object _property;  
public object Property  
{  
    get { return _property; }  
    set  
    {  
        if (_property != value)  
        {  
            _property = value;  
            Dispatcher.DelayInvoke("PropertyChanged_Property",(Action)(() =>
            {
                 RaisePropertyChanged("Property");   
            }),TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));

        }  
    }  
}
```

Not sure i like it though...

Answer (score -1):

A typical pattern for this case, is implementing your property as

```
    private object _property;
    public object Property
    {
        get { return _property; }
        set
        {
            if (_property != value)
            {
                _property = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Property");
            }
        }
    }
```

which will update your binding only if the value changed

Comment: I think Nickolay uses this pattern, but property changes very fast.

Comment: If he would, a change to the property would'nt trigger an update to the UI, so there shouldn´t be any concerns regarding wasted ressources caused by UI updating

Answer (score -1):

In this case a timer triggering the UI update is the way to go. To keep the UI fluent take an timer interval of about 40ms.

```cs
public class ViewModel
{
    private Timer updateTimer;
    public ViewModel()
    {
        updateTimer = new Timer();
        updateTimer.Interval = 40;
        updateTimer.Elapsed +=new ElapsedEventHandler(updateTimer_Elapsed);
        updateTimer.Start();
    }

    private object _property;
    public object Property
    {
        get { return _property; }
        set
        {
            if (_property != value)
            {
                _property = value;
            }
        }
    } 

    void  updateTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Calling `RaisePropertyChanged()` without an argument forces the UI to refresh all bindings. If you don't want this, you could use flags or a registry, to mark which property needs to be updated.

Comment: Introducing the timer causes more damage than help, that viewmodel class is going to be rooted because of the event handler. Dont try to handle thinks WPF can handle for you

Comment: I don't see the point were this is more damage than help. WPF handles the UI and its updates as always. I just want to control the indication of property changes by an elapsing timer.

Comment: As sad because you add an eventhandler which you´ll have to manually take care of once you want your ViewModel to get garbage collected